# Build shema.yml file with current database in memory to compare with available schema.yml

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

I have been trying to create schema.yml content in memory from a behavior I have written. I want to test if any changes made by a developer to schema.yml comply with the current database fields and foreign key references. I see the task class that builds schema, but havenot been able to find straightforward way to do that or am I missing something here? Can this be done by leveraging the symfony api already available rather than writing my own solution?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am using Propel as ORM

Comment: Which version of propel?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you tweak the migration task to define difference between your current schema (in memory) and the one potentially modified by the developer?

```
php symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-diff
```

This task generate a diff between generated classes and current `schema.yml`.

What you can do:

- generate new model (form and filter) based on the new `schema.yml`
- put this change into a new folder (not defaults one)
- run the task `doctrine:generate-migrations-diff` an give it the path for new models (forms and filters)
- if it generates migrations classes: developper made some change, if not, every thing is ok.

**Edit:** (since the OP use propel)

You have almost the same task [in Propel](https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin/blob/master/lib/task/sfPropelMigrateTask.class.php) (and [the doc](http://www.propelorm.org/documentation/10-migrations.html)).